# .htaccess determine the HTTP_HOST

Tags: .htaccess

I have a multi-tenant site that spans across 3 different domain names. So for example:

```
client1.website.com
client2.website.net
client3.website.us
etc
```

In PHP I can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the host name and determine if they are on `website.com`, `website.net`, etc.

I want to do the same in my `.htaccess` file as I have a couple of rewrite conditions.

Here they are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^regionapi\.website\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^website\.com$ [NC]
```

Can I do something like this?

```
domain = %{HTTP_HOST}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^regionapi\.{domain}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^{domain}$ [NC]
```

I might be way off but it would be great if this can work.

Comment: That expression doesn't make sense, if `domain` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` are interchangeable at all times, then both does conditions will always fail

Comment: @BenSinclair: Many conditions can be applied but you need to clarify your requirement with examples for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using something such as the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?regionapi\.example\.(com|net|us)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.%2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Depending on the domain name extension `regionapi.example.(com,net,us)` would redirect to:

```
http://example.(com,net,us)
```